# How to identify the keys to power in a government?

Tags: political-theory, power

I am interested in predicting the political dynamics of a country. I really like CGP Grey's explanation of the [rules for rulers](https://youtu.be/rStL7niR7gs?si=nz81UuZTXQ1V2TD8), and I wanted to use that as my framework for prediction.

The basic idea of this video is that a ruler must satisfy the keys to power much like a CEO does with a board of directors since no ruler rules alone.

So my question is this: **Is there a viable method to determine using OSINT (open-source intelligence), who the keys are in any arbitrary government ?**

Answer (score 8):

AFAICT that's some simplified (one might say clickbait) version of [selectorate theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selectorate_theory).  One of the [criticisms](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev-polisci-071213-041224) of this theory is that where the "keys" start may be obvious, at least in a "steady state", e.g. the head of the army would generally be included, but how far you draw that circle in fact it isn't clear, particularly in less authoritarian systems/regimes. And even for the latter, e.g. in the case of "unsteady state"--change of balance of power(s) coup by one army group (for instance), it's also becoming less clear.

> The concept was later generalized to apply across ruler selection mechanisms in all types of regimes in The Logic of Political Survival (LPS) by Bueno de Mesquita et al. (2003), which adds the notion of the winning coalition as a subset of the selectorate sufficient in size for a ruler to attain power. [...]
>
> It can be useful for an initial stab at predicting general tendencies in politics, but it is not the right tool for every job, nor is it advisable for detailed work. [...]
>
> Lack of clarity about the locus of power is a distinguishing feature of authoritarian systems. The focus on a selectorate, moreover, underestimates the role of the unenfranchised members of society—what others term the “ejectorate” (Zimmerman 2014). Second, the measurement of the sizes of the selectorate and winning coalition is problematic, calling into question the empirical findings in LPS, such as its central claims about the survival of rulers. Third, the assumptions in the LPS version of the theory are restrictive in ways that reduce the utility of the selectorate concept relative to earlier works. In particular, LPS assumes that the members of the selectorate are homogeneous, and it unrealistically links public goods and political rights. As a result, the only relevant feature of the winning coalition is its size, and the theory struggles to explain policy change in the authoritarian context and why dictators may combine carrots and sticks to deal with opposition.

As for the earlier/narrower goals:

> Given the opacity of political transition and succession politics in Soviet-style regimes, however, the immediate goals of analysts employing the selectorate concept were much more limited.   In most cases, they developed ways to study and measure the approximate size, composition, and preferences of the Communist Party elite that seemed to have a formal role in the selection or removal of top leaders, including the removal of Khrushchev in 1964, the subsequent selection and long tenure of Brezhnev, and the rise of Deng Xiaoping and Mikhail Gorbachev as reformist leaders. “When Communists rule, it is not the electorate but what may be called the ‘selectorate’ which counts, and any analysis of the political potential of particular leaders has to take into account the size, composition, and cohesion of the ‘selectorate’ and the factors influencing its decisions” (Stern 1978, p. 340). Selectorate analysis examined the generation, educational background, ethnicity, and professional career and network of Party leaders, often including elite members of the Party in the military and in regional positions, even those outside of the formal selectorate defined as the Central Committee of the Party Congress. This variant of elite analysis is alive and well in studies of Chinese politics (Li 2001, Shih et al. 2012; China Leadership Monitor, various years).

However, even this kind of analysis runs into some fuzzy boundaries problems:

> Although Roeder and Shirk offer compelling and logical accounts of leadership and policy dynamics in the USSR and China, they are not able to demonstrate empirically two core claims: first, that the Central Committee actually maintained accountability over higher leaders in the politburo, its standing committee, and the coterie of retired “elders” (in China); and second, that the selectorate was located solely within this body given the importance of the military and other Party elites (Yang 1996). The make-up of a selectorate and how it morphs over time in size, composition, and preferences are crucial empirical issues; as Stern asks (1978, p. 343), “If the core of the ‘selectorate’ lies in the Party, how far up the Communist ladder does one have to go to find it?” Moreover, the problem in determining the identity of the selectorate is not merely academic, as uncertainty is a core characteristic of autocratic systems. For example, “[w]ith the levers of political, military, and economic power in diverse and often highly ambitious hands after Stalin's death, there was for a time considerable confusion as to the ultimate source of political patronage” (Stern 1978, p. 343).
>
> Zimmerman's (2014) recent analysis of Soviet and Russian politics traces the expansion and contraction of the Soviet selectorate over time, indicating both the amorphous boundaries of its membership and the difficulty in defining it when both selection and removal of leaders occur irregularly and without clearly defined electoral or even “selectoral” mechanisms. Zimmerman also points to a related problem in defining the role of the unenfranchised when votes are no longer the currency in which power is traded. Building on Schumpeter's insight that electorates in democracies have not only a “primary function” to produce a government but also “the function of evicting it” (Schumpeter 2003 [1943], p. 272), Soviet citizens constituted not the unenfranchised but the “ejectorate,” the body of people who had the collective power to remove governments via extralegal means (Zimmerman 2014, p. 3).

Although that piece doesn't discuss South Korea as a case, its coups in the 1950s-1970s are another interesting point in the difficulty of applying the theory with some predictive power. (I mean sure, you can say the army ruled in general, but which faction was in the ascendancy often was not correlated with official posts they had, until after a coup. So determining when the overt power/keys were becoming shaky is not terribly obvious, just as it was not always obvious in the Soviet regimes who had most influence with the leader etc.)

> In authoritarian regimes, especially where rulers do not attain power through some institutionalized process, the concepts of selectorate size and minimum winning coalition size do not have a clear meaning.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to selectorate theory that offer better predictive power ?

Comment: "cohesion of the ‘selectorate’ and the factors influencing its decisions" : Follow the money. Which is becoming more and more difficult. For Russia, start with fertilizer and natural gas.